# Android List Item: TextView on left, Image on right

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm creating a custom list item in and android list view. it's very simple, it has a textview on the left and an image on the right. the image should align all the way right, and the text view should take up all the space on the left. problem is, i can get the image to show up, but it pushes left. if i set the textview width to fill_parent, the image disappears. here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:orientation="horizontal" 
              android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="50px" android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
  <!-- item -->
  <TextView android:id="@+id/txtItem" android:gravity="center_vertical" android:textSize="20px" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>

  <!-- disclosure image -->
  <ImageView android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical" android:src="@drawable/common_icon_arrow_disclosure" 
              android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

i've also tried a relative layout, but the same thing happens. what am i doing wrong?

---

EDIT: for clarification, this is what i'm trying to accomplish:

[image]

i want the text field to take up the whole left area, and the image to be on the right, unscaled, vertically centered.

Answer (score 30):

You can also just add the drawable to the textview directly like this.

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/txtItem"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:drawableRight="@drawable/common_icon_arrow_disclosure"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:textSize="20px" />
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the TextView will automatically set the compound drawable near to it's bounds.

Comment: but how can we perform onClick action on only drawable image? not whole text??

Comment: Can't believe I've never found that one before. Thanks!

Comment: textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, R.drawable.common_icon_arrow_disclosure, 0)

Answer (score 10):

You can use bitmap drawable like this (this also adds rounded corners):

```
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <shape>
            <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
            <stroke
                android:width="2dp"
                android:color="#adadad"
            />
            <corners android:radius="5dp" />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:right="5dp"
        android:top="2dp"
        android:bottom="2dp">
        <bitmap
            android:src="@drawable/image"
            android:gravity="right"
        />
    </item>
</layer-list>
```

and put this drawable in background property of your TextView:

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/right_image"
    android:text="some text"
    />
```

Comment: Thankyou! This also works for setting a custom background and down arrow icon for a spinner control. Just set the background of your spinner to a drawable resource defined like this and you're set.

Answer (score 1):

Left-align your text with the parent, and set the gravity of the image to right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="48dp">

  <TextView
  android:id="@+id/team_member_name"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
  android:gravity="center_vertical"
  android:singleLine="true"/>

  <ImageView
  android:id="@+id/team_member_icon"
  android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
  android:layout_width="wrap_content"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:layout_gravity="right"
  android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
  android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
  android:src="@drawable/circle_green"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Relative layout is what you want. In your case the fill_parent attribute was causing the text view to push the image off of the screen. If you use Relative layout and set the text view to use the layout_toLeftOf it should work.

Here is a quick example that I think will work (I haven't tested it out and it's from memory but the idea is there)...

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="50px"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical">
  <ImageView android:id="@+id/img"
             android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
             android:src="@drawable/common_icon_arrow_disclosure" 
             android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

  <TextView android:id="@+id/txtItem"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:textSize="20px"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/img" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: That doesn't work either. the arrow image showsup, but the text doesn't. also, the arrow (which is less tall than the item) is not centered vertically, instead it's aligned top. i actually had something very similar, but it had the imageView with layout_toRightOf the text image, but that did just the opposite of your example, the text showed up, but not the arrow.

Comment: Sorry that I don't have the time to write up a test case but something else you might try is the *layout_alignParentLeft* instead of *layout_gravity*. I know I've done exactly what you are asking for but I can't find it in my projects and I know it used the RelativeLayout. Good luck and I'll check back in tomorrow if I can.

Comment: i used layout_alignParentRight="true" on the imageView (i switched the image view and the text view, since the image view is on the right,it really should be declared second). the problem is twofold; i can get both the text view and the img view to show, but 1) the image view is not vertically centered - as i mentioned, the image is actually smaller than the row height, and 2) the image view is not aligned to the right, instead it follows right after the end of the text. if i change the text view to have a layout_width="fill_parent", the image view disappears again. :(

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView android:id="@+id/date"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_color"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"/>

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageBtn"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:contentDescription="@string/delete"
    android:src="@drawable/delete_minus_png"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Line android:layout_marginRight="10dp" did the trick.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Looks like there is some layout bug or so.  If the TextView has fill_parent flag, the ImageView will be pushed away from the layout, even if the TextView contents are small enough.