# Trying to show thumbnail images on the side of the listview

Tags: android, listview

I currently have a `listview` that shows all the .cue files in a directory in alphabetical order after selecting it, it uses and external program to handle the .cue file. what i would like to do is to show thumbnails matching the cue file in an `imageview` at the background. for example if i have a file named "a.cue" and "a.png" in the same directory, when "a.cue" is highlighted in the `listview`, 
"a.png" is shown as a thumbnail in the background at the same time. Here is my current code:

```
public class openfileactivity7 extends Activity {

File path;
ListView list;
static ArrayList<String> bin_paths=new ArrayList<String>();
static ArrayList<String> bin_names=new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    if (audioplay.isplayingAudio) {


    } else {audioplay.playAudio(this, R.raw.boot);

    }



    list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.listView1);


    bin_paths.clear();
    bin_names.clear();


    path = new File("/mnt/usb_storage/USB_DISK0/udisk0/cue/pcecd");
    searchFolderRecursive1(path);




    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, android.R.id.text1, bin_names);


    Collections.sort(bin_paths);
    Collections.sort(bin_names);

    adapter.sort(new Comparator<String>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(String lhs, String rhs) {
            return lhs.compareTo(rhs);
        }
    });



    list.setAdapter(adapter);


    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                                long arg3) {

            String path = bin_paths.get(arg2);
            File file = new File(path);
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            intent.setDataAndType(Uri.fromFile(file), "application/cue");
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY);
            startActivity(intent);
            if (audioplay.isplayingAudio) {
                audioplay.stopAudio();
            }
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
}




private static void searchFolderRecursive1(File folder)
{
    if (folder != null)
    {
        if (folder.listFiles() != null)
        {
            for (File file : folder.listFiles())
            {
                if (file.isFile())
                {

                    if(file.getName().contains(".cue"))
                    {
                        //   Log.e("ooooooooooooo", "path__="+file.getName());
                        file.getPath();
                        bin_names.add(file.getName());
                        bin_paths.add(file.getPath());
                        //    Log.e("bin_paths", ""+bin_names);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    searchFolderRecursive1(file);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}


}
```

Comment: what is the question here? Also, you're not pretending people will read all the code for you, and fix it? Just tell us where the real problem is, how far you go, and what's the real stopper for you.

Comment: i guess the question is, I am a beginner of a programmer and while i understand how to display and imageview and understand how listview works, i am unsure if they can be implemented side by side. I am not expecting people to fix it by any means but if they can point to a resource or example to a similar case in question (as i searched and could not find an answer) would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you mean something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9452989/how-to-have-a-listview-with-icons-beside-the-text first link googling for the issue ... I wonder did you even google before to post on SO

Comment: Or this? Second link: https://androidcookbook.com/Recipe.seam;jsessionid=E29F9B569793C059A30F20AA3F5A5C0C?recipeId=830

Comment: i did. several times. I apologize for being a beginner and appreciate you showing me some examples.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4357046/8089770

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=listview+with+image+on+left+and+textview+android&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8

Comment: https://www.android-examples.com/android-custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-using-arrayadapter-string/

Comment: @DannyAlvarado no need to apologize, everyone of us has to start from somewhere. Do my links help to get you going?

Comment: i took a look at all the examples posted but they kind of are what i kept running into when searching. all those examples have the issue that they require a custom array adapter where the images being used are already known. in the case of my code they are subject to change since the user would be able to remove .cue files or add them together with the images. the activity checks for all the files in the usb directory when it is ran. I again apologize if i am not explaining it correctly. I asked because i was not even sure if what i am asking can be accomplished with android studio and java.

Comment: You would need, I think, your own data adapter anyhow. Upon changes of the dataset (the .cue files) you would need to refresh the dataset accordingly. Atm you're using a StringAdapter which is an adapter for String types. Have a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21833181/arrayadapter-text-and-image

Comment: Or maybe this way: https://www.android-examples.com/android-custom-listview-with-imageview-and-textview-using-arrayadapter-string/ here an ArrayAdapter<String> is used, and when returning the view, the view itself is manipulated so to set both text and image. I still would rather implement my own adapter.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following example (The code below is not tested).

1) MainActivity.class-------------------

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements ItemAdapter.Listener {

private ListView lv;
private ItemAdapter itemAdapter;
private List<String> bin_names;
private List<String> bin_paths;
private List<String> bin_images_paths;
private static final String NO_IMAGE = "no_image";

@Override
protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.demo11);

    //Search for .cue files --- populate bin_names --- populate bin_path ---
    // check if an image (in the same directory) for the corresponding .cue file exists:
    // if yes add image path otherwise add NO_IMAGE.

    // done with data population part...

    lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.lv);
    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(getApplication() , bin_names , bin_paths , bin_images_paths , MainActivity.this);
    lv.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    if(itemAdapter != null){// refresh data
        itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
}

@Override
public void PlayM(int position) {
    //open file
    // get file path by using bin_paths.get(position).
    File file = new File(bin_paths.get(position));
    if(file.exists()){
        if(file.getName().contains(".cue")){
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext() , "Play " + bin_paths.get(position) , Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }else{
            //refresh data.
            if(itemAdapter != null){
                itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        }
    }else{
        //refresh data.
        if(itemAdapter != null){
            itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    }

}
}
```

2) ItemAdapter.class---------------------------

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context mContext;
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;
private Listener callback;

private List<String> n = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> p = new ArrayList<String>();
private List<String> i = new ArrayList<String>();


public ItemAdapter(Context c , List<String> n , List<String> p , List<String> i , Listener l) {
    mContext = c;
    callback = l;
    this.n = n; //names
    this.p = p; //paths
    this.i = i; //images;
    layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

}

public int getCount() {
    return p.size();
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return p.get(position);
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    TextView tv;
    ImageView iv;
    View view = convertView;


    if (convertView == null) {
        if (layoutInflater != null) {
            view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.demo10, null);
        }
    }

    tv = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tv);
    iv = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.iv);

    File file = new File(p.get(position));
    if(file.exists()){
        if(!file.getName().contains(".cue")){// is not a .cue file
            n.remove(position);
            p.remove(position);
            i.remove(position);
            this.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }else{
            //everything is fine.
            tv.setText(n.get(position));
            tv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    if(callback != null) {
                        callback.PlayM(position);
                    }
                }
            });

            File image = new File(i.get(position)); // check if image exists
            if(image.exists()){
                if(image.getName().contains(".jpg") || image.getName().contains(".png")){

                    Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(i.get(position));
                    iv.setImageBitmap(b);
                    iv.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View view) {
                            if(callback != null){
                                callback.PlayM(position);
                            }
                        }
                    });

                }else{
                    // hide imageView
                    iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                }
            }else{
                // hide imageView
                iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }

        }
    }else{ // doesn't exist
        n.remove(position);
        p.remove(position);
        i.remove(position);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    return view;
}

public interface Listener {
    public void PlayM(int position);
}
}
```

3) demo11.xml--------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/lv">
</ListView>

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

4) demo10.xml-------------------

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/tv"
    android:textSize="17sp"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@id/iv"
    android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:text="Name"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:layout_weight="20"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/iv"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```